# Can I cancel my Ryanair flight for free within 24 hours?

Tags: cancellations, ryanair

Can I cancel a Ryanair flight I boutght less than 24 hours ago for free?

I've hear and read somewhere that this is possible with some companies. Is Ryanair one of this? How do I cancel the flight for free, if possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

> All Ryanair flights are changeable but they cannot be cancelled.

https://www.ryanair.com/sk/en/useful-info/help-centre/faq-overview/Flight-Changes-And-Refunds/Can-I-cancel-my-booking-before-travel

The policy you are probably thinking about is mainly a US requirement that flights to and within the US are freely cancelable for a 24 hour period after purchase.  This does not, obviously, include Ryanair.

Comment: SAS and Pegasus also offer it, and Norwegian within 4 hours

Comment: So the only thing I can get back, if I apply within one month, is this _government tax_. Do you know how much it is?

Comment: @Crazydre as i said, “mainly” - the 24 hour period is what made the link for me.  But Ryanair is definitely not one.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis that entirely depends on which government tax is being applied, as Ryanair flies to and from many different countries.  In the UK, there would be the Air Passenger Duty levied which you could be refunded, and in other countries it might be something different.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis The government tax varies. In the UK I think it's 12-13 pounds

Comment: The flight I was thinking about cancelling is from Italy to UK.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis these are discussions you need to have with Ryanair, we cant help you with specifics because we dont know the breakdown of your ticket.  There may be many things you can claim back - airport fees, local development fees, government taxes etc etc etc.

Comment: There may be an admin fee for cancellation that would cancel out the refund of airport taxes etc

Comment: @Traveller As one who has cancelled Ryanair flights in the past, I can confirm that an administration fee will indeed be applied. The fee amount could even exceed the value of the refundable amount.

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can - but Ryanair doesn't like you doing it so you have to call them. There is no means to electronically do this.

Comment: This is clearly the opposite of what Ryanair declares at the link in the other answer.

Comment: Can you please tell use why you mention this. Is it personal experience and if so, how often and was it yourself or do you have it from stories of others?